# What is delegate and how it allows to create objects

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

If delegates are Abstract then how it allows to create object

Answer (score 4):

**delegate** is a type safe function pointer. It is a reference type in C#.

```
 delegate result-type identifier ([parameters]);
```

However the **Delegate class** is not a delegate type, it's a class used to derive delegate types, thus it is abstract [(check for more clarification)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A delegate looks like a typesafe function pointer, of course to understand that you'd need to know what a function pointer is and why typesafety is important, but it's more than that.

Under the covers a delegate is a class with an Invoke method, the Invoke method is created at compile time to have the same signature as the delegate definition. So if I do

delegate int MyDelegate(string s);

I'd end up with something like

```
class MyDelegate : MulticastDelegate
{
    int Invoke(string s) {...}
}
```

I can use this in code like this

```
int SomeFunc(string s)
{
    // do something with s and return an int
}

MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(SomeFunc);
```

then either

```
int a = del.Invoke("Foo");
```

or simply

```
int a = del("Foo");
```

It's this last usage that makes it look like a function pointer ('del' is pointing to the SomeFunc function), and it's typesafe because it only takes and returns the types defined (the rules are a bit more complicated than this).

You also now have other ways of calling the delegate notable anonymous methods and lambdas but that's beyond the scope of this

A lot of this happens with compiler magic, for example turning the delegate definition into a class definition and turning the call to the method into a call to Invoke.

HTH